# res.cookie("access", value) Cookie is not storing on browser

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, setcookie, express-jwt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82lAo.png)I was trying to store jwt token as Cookie in the browser but it is not storing it in browser, But in the postman it's is working fine, in the browser I am getting Set-Cookie=value in response-headers
even tried to store using libraries like js-cookie it stored at first time, but when I tries again it's not storing it

this is Login function I am using to store it

```
export const userLogin = async (request, response, next) => {
    const { email, password } = request.body;

    try {

        const isUserAvailable = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

        if (!isUserAvailable) {
            return response.status(NOT_ACCEPTABLE).json({ error: true, statusCode: NOT_ACCEPTABLE, message: `User Not Found !` })
    }

        const isPasswordCorrect = await isPasswordValid(password, isUserAvailable.password);

        if (isPasswordCorrect) {
            const expiryDate = new Date();
            expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 1);
            const accessToken = await generateToken(isUserAvailable._id,    isUserAvailable.username);
            console.log("access controller", accessToken)


            response.cookie('access_token', accessToken, {
                httpOnly: true, path: "/",
            }).status(OK)
                .json({
                    error: false, statusCode: OK, message: `Login Successful`, accessToken, data: {
                        uid: isUserAvailable._id, fullName: isUserAvailable.fullName, username:   isUserAvailable.username, email: isUserAvailable.email,
                        avatar: isUserAvailable.avatar, mobile: isUserAvailable.mobile
                    }
                })
        } else {
            response.status(FORBIDDEN).json({ error: true, statusCode: FORBIDDEN, message:   `Invalid Password` })
        }

    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}

in the below function I am trying to retrieve it
import Jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

    export const userAuthByToken = (request, response, next) => {
        try {

            const token = request.cookies.access_token;
   
            console.log("token auth", request.cookies_access_token)
 
            if (!token) {
                return response.status(401).json({ error: true, message: 'User is Un-Authorized' });
            }

            Jwt.verify(token.accessToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (error, user) => {
                 if (error) return response.status(401).json({ error: true, message: "Forbidden" });
                request.user = user;
                next()
            })
        } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    }
}
```

but it's not working and when I console.log I am getting null object

Answer (score 0):

well I got answer for my question
I have changed in response like below

```
response.cookie('access_token', token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            domain: "localhost",
            origin: "http://localhost:1234",
            path: "/api/estates",
            sameSite: "None",
            expires: expiryDate,
            secure: true,
        }).status(OK)
            .json({
                error: false, statusCode: OK, message: `Login Successful`, access_token: token, data: {
                    uid: isUserAvailable._id, fullName: isUserAvailable.fullName, username: isUserAvailable.username, email: isUserAvailable.email,
                    avatar: isUserAvailable.avatar, mobile: isUserAvailable.mobile
                }
            })
```

I have provided path, domain, origin and secure flag now the token is getting stored in Cookies section in browser